# how to replay block I/O trace file in csv format

Tags: trace

I'm trying to replay MS-Cambridge I/O trace, which is converted in csv file, but I don't know how to convert this csv file into blktrace binary file, which can be replayed by fio or else.
Can anyone answer me how to convert csv formatted I/O trace into replay-able binary format?

Answer (score 0):

https://ysoh.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/706/ talks about converting SNIA Cambridge trace files to Disksim but unfortunately I've yet to see anything about getting the CSV or Disksim files into `blktrace` format. It may be easier to convert those files into [fio's trace v2 format](http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#trace-file-format-v2) (as that is just ASCII) and then you can use [fio](https://github.com/axboe/fio/) to play it back...

Answer (score 0):

As what Anon said, you could convert csv file to a simple ASCII file (e.g. trace.log), and make a fio test config file (e.g. test.fio). Then use `fio test.fio` in your command.

Specifically, I give the example of these two files:

trace.log:

```
fio version 2 iolog
/dev/loop1 add
/dev/loop1 open
/dev/loop1 write 0 4096
/dev/loop1 write 4096 4096
/dev/loop1 close
```

test.fio:

```
[write-test]
ioengine=libaio
iodepth=32
direct=1
thread=1
read_iolog=trace.log
```

Hope it helps you understand.